# Getting Location information

Tags: security, geolocation, gsm, triangulation, gpsd

I'm to work on a project that will use anyone's phone number to determine his/her current location without the person installing any app on his phone. The GPS/GSM cell towers or nearby wifi devices will be used to access the person's location. How do I go about this please? Any library or modules recommendation? Can I achieve this with python?

I understand how most tracking devices work Is that the user will install an app, the app gets the user Current location using either his gps, wifi or gsm location, the app sends the received location to a server, the server is accessed from a webview and monitor the location.

But to get the location using just phone number, how do I achieve that?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it. You can learn [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I do not think this question is a useful one for stack overflow, I'm going to recommend you check out multilateration. This technique uses 3 or more cell towers and measures the signal to each of them, allowing you to triangulate a position from the signal. This can be done without the standard GPS system (using a satellite), but is far less accurate and I imagine you will need an application installed on the phone to do the bulk of the work.